# How to make compile faster in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am going to convert `HTML` design to `Vue js` design by using `vuetify`.
But I have a problem with that works.

I copy all `HTML` code to the `app.vue` ( ...copy )
and then import all `bootstrap.css` (that used in `HTML`)
Here html code have about 9000 lines.

And then run next command in terminal: `yarn serve`

However, the compile takes much long time (about 3 hours).
so I checked the net connection state and computer, then there is no problem.

I want to know the reason of my problem and to improve compile speed.
thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGTi6.png)